# Ansible playbook targeting two groups

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible playbook that upgrades Kubernetes version on the minions.

```
- name: Configure and start the Kubernetes Nodes
  hosts: kubernetes-minions
  serial: 1
  tasks:
   - name: backup K8S master files.
      shell: "{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - cp /etc/kubernetes/config /var/tmp/k8s-backup/
        - cp /etc/kubernetes/kubelet /var/tmp/k8s-backup/
   - name: cordon the minion.
      command: kubectl cordon {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}
      delegate_to: kubernetes-master
   - name: Install latest version of Docker on Minion.
      yum: name=kubernetes-1.3.0-0.3.git86dc49a.el7 state=present
   - name: start the kubernetes kubelet
      service: name=kubelet state=restarted enabled=yes
   - name: start the kubernetes kube-proxy
      service: name=kube-proxy state=restarted enabled=yes
   - name: uncordon the minion.
      command: kubectl uncordon {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}
      delegate_to: kubernetes-master
```

My inventory file looks like::

```
[kubernetes-masters]
172.29.219.102

[kubernetes-minions]
172.29.219.105
172.29.219.106
172.29.219.107
```

Now I have defined the target group tp be `hosts: kubernetes-minions` where the actual `yum update` is supposed to happen but before this step is run on EACH minion, I need to cordon this nodes on the `kubernetes-master`

Now the problem that I am having is how to tell ansible that for the step of cordon/uncordon , do it on the kubernetes-master node rather than the minion. I tried to use `delegate_to: kubernetes-master` but seems like its running the step on the minion itself.

EDIT :: **The upgrade on the minions will be done sequentially and not in parallel to minimize downtime.**

Comment: @techraf For the sake of automation, I want to keep things as simple as possible. When you mention two plays, do you mean one play to cordon/uncordon on the master and the other play to update the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `delegate_to` indentation (should be on same level as task) and select single master from your group:

hosts:

```
[kubernetes-masters]
ku1

[kubernetes-minions]
ku2
ku3
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: kubernetes-minions
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  serial: 1
  tasks:
      - debug: msg="cordon"
        delegate_to: "{{ groups['kubernetes-masters'] | first }}"

      - debug: msg="update minion"

      - debug: msg="uncordon"
        delegate_to: "{{ groups['kubernetes-masters'] | first }}"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for. Since Im relatively new to Ansible im learning on various strategies. Is there a link to any documentation that specifies how to use IPs/Groups in a playbook. I mean how can I invoke specific values in a playbook that are defined under groups in my inventory file.

Comment: Most relevant docs about this topic is [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).